# FOSUserBundle Confirmation after registration

Tags: symfony

I have activated in the FOSUserBundle the email confirmation. It allows users to receive a link by mail after
they registration.

```
registration:
    confirmation:
        enabled: true
```

But It's not really what I want.
I just want to send a welcome mail to confirm their registration (with no confirmation link).

Is it possible to configurate that in the FOSUserBundle?

Comment: Configured, I don't think so, but can be implement for sure, maybe you just need to find what event is called after registration and implement the task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a custom template for the email sent after registration:

```
confirmation:
    enabled:    true
    template:   YourUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
```

Copy the default `FOSUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig` and remove the confirmation link.

But as the `confirmation` is set to `true`, your users will not be `enabled` by default.

So, if you want disable the whole confirmation feature, you can:

- [Override the `FOS\UserBundle\Controller\RegistrationController`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_controllers.html) to send a custom e-mail
- [Create a listener that send a custom e-mail on`FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_CONFIRMED`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/controller_events.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: `FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents` is not found in my vendor. I'm using the version 1.3.x of the FOSUserBundle!!! Is it a new feature in the version 2 ?

Comment: Yes, this feature is only available since 2.0. You need to use the firt of the two last options I given, that is overriding the RegistrationController. Create  an email sending method into and call it from the registerAction in case of success.

Comment: Ok so I have created my class `RegisterController` in the same path in my Bundle child. But the override doesn't seems to work. Is there something else to do in a .yml file? Like for exemple changing the provider. How does symfony know that it has to use my class now? ps: I'm using the SonataUserbundhe with FOSUserBundle.

Comment: I just see your comment, sorry. [This question should help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18571884/sonatauserbundle-fosuserbundle-overriding-controllers), tell me if it doesn't.